# Schedule weekly Webi report using SDK

Tags: business-objects, webi, business-objects-sdk

I am trying to schedule a Webi report using SDK, I can schedule Once, Monthly and other types.

Could anyone tell me how to schedule a Webi report weekly?

I can set the schedule type to WEEKLY and start and end date, but there is no API available for setting days of the week on which report will schedule.

Also, user doesn't have access to any Calendar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlike the other modes.  You have to get the ICalendarRunDays object and add days into it.

Assuming you're using the Java SDK, and you have the object's `ISchedulingInfo` as `iSched`:

```
iSched.setType(CeScheduleType.CALENDAR);
iSched.getCalendarRunDays().add(ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, java.util.Calendar.MONDAY, ICalendarDay.ALL);
iSched.getCalendarRunDays().add(ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, ICalendarDay.ALL, java.util.Calendar.WEDNESDAY, ICalendarDay.ALL);
```

This is the "proper" way to do it.  You could replace all the `ICalendarDay.ALL` references with `-1`.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I was trying the same way, but the trick was CeScheduleType.Calendar ... I was trying CeScheduleType.Weekly. I figure that out very late. Thanks for the answer. Have one more question, How to check that the given Password is not a Last N password using SDK. changePassword( oldPassword,                        newPassword)neither return anything nor throw any exception.

Comment: That really should be a new question, but you'll get the exception when you call IInfoStore.commit() (which is necessary for the password change to take effect).

Comment: Thanks Joe, I always missed the commit thing. wasted so many hours on commit recently. ( Very New to BO ) Thanks a lot.. solved my problem.